# Add a element to a 2D time series in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, append, time-series

I have a very simple problem but I am wondering if there is a simpler way to solve it (they must be).

I have a matrix which is 10 by 10 and contains double. I need to create a time serie with those data points.

The way i am doing it is as follow. I create a 3D array with the thrid dimension being the time. And everyday I add the new data in the array by increasing the time dimension by one.

Here is the code:

```
    TS_updated = zeros(size(TS_Current)+[0,0,1]);
    TS_updated(:,:,1:end-1) = TS_Current;
    TS_updated(:,:,end) = TS_New;
```

where TS_Current is the existing 3D array representing the time serie and TS_New is the new data from today which I need to add to the time series.

Is there a quicker way to append the last element such as with 2D table:

```
TS_updated = [TS_Current;TS_New];
```

Or even maybe a smarter way to store the time serie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `cat` function ([documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html)) in the third dimension:

```
TS_updated = cat(3, TS_Current, TS_New);
```

You could include error checking first by using

```
% Check dimensions 1 and 2 are consistent first
if size(TS_Current,1) == size(TS_New,1) && size(TS_Current,2) == size(TS_New,2) 
    % Now concatenate
    TS_updated = cat(2, TS_Current, TS_New);
else
    error('New time series has incorrect dimensions')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
TS(:,:,end+1) = TS_new;
```

And you might also want to preallocate if you intend to extend the series more often than once per day. You can start with any length and double space when that limit is reached.

There is no clearly better way of arranging data I could see. You might flatten it to 100xTime instead of 10x10xTime, but it depends whether it would help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to concatenate in the 3rd dimension?

```
A=ones(3,3,2)
B=rand(3,3);
C=cat(3,A,B)
```